# I have a continuous loop and I cannot figure out what is wrong with it

Tags: c, floating-point, infinite-loop

I have a continuous loop in my C code and I cannot figure out why exactly it is acting this way. I feel that I am missing something noticable here but I just can't see it for some reason. Here is the segment of the code that is causing the loop:

```
while (err > 0.0000001) {
    if (err != 1.0) {
        bab = ((2.0*bab) + input/(pow(bab, 2)))/3.0;
        printf("The approximate cube root is %.3lf\n", bab);
        err = input - bab;
    }
    else {
        bab = ((2.0*app) + input/(pow(app, 2)))/3.0;
        printf("The approximate cube root is %.3lf\n", bab);
        err = input - bab;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What input value or values would you expect to cause the loop to exit?

Comment: `if (err != 1.0)` - Never test for equality with floating-point numbers.

Comment: Read this about floating point numbers, to complement what @JonathonReinhart is talking about: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: The common term is "infinite loop", FYI

Comment: The most apparent cause of this infinite loop is that either err never converges to the level at which you are testing, or it does so very slowly.  Try printing err from the loop.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart You are right about FP numbers,but doesn't that matter when we are testing `equality` or `inequality`?In the `while`'s condition, we are checking for `>`.Would that be problem as well?

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture, of course you can test `<` and `>`. And I said, "never test for equality" (which implies inequality as well).

Comment: Do you guys have an example of how you would write an inequality as a reference? Doesnt need to be my code, but just an example of how to write an inequality using floating point numbers

Answer (score 3):

`bab` is (sooner or later) approximately the cube root of `input`. You set

```
err = input - bab;
```

and test

```
while (err > 0.0000001)
```

So if `input > 1 + 3*1e-7` (roughly), the difference `input - cube_root(input)` is larger than your threshold.

You probably want to set

```
err = abs(input - bab*bab*bab);
```

to control the quality of the approximation to the cube root of `input`.

Comment: +1.I knew there was problem with the maths used in the program,but then, I am so miserable at maths!

Comment: I am trying to use this math to show how its equivalent to just using the pow function, so the slight inaccuracies shows that they are not equal, but thank you for the great idea